# How do I add custom tags in the head of my razor views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to add custom javascript in the head of certain views.  I have the normal structuring, with a shared folder that has a view called _Layout.cshtml.  This file has the head tag in it and is the basic "master page" for all my views.  I want a certain view to have certain javascript in the head tag, but have everything else the same, how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out the @RenderSection method.  you pass it a name and whether the section is required (yours would be false), and then in your views you set that section up using @Section.

to sum up, put something like this in your layout:

```
@RenderSection("OptionalContent", required: false)
```

and something like this in your view:

```
@section ExtraContent {
    <div>Some extra content</div>
}
```